# accessing a specific constraint from array of constraints

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

lets say you have an array of constraints

```
let constraints = [NSLayoutConstraints]
```

And I want to access the top anchor somehow using subscripts.  I tried

```
extension Array where Element: NSLayoutConstraint {

enum LayoutAnchor {
    case top
    //case left
    //case bottom
    //case right
}

subscript(anchor: LayoutAnchor) -> NSLayoutConstraint? {
    switch anchor {
    case .top: return self.index(of: topAnchor)
    }
}
}
```

so I can call `anchors[.top]` to access the top anchor.  How would I directly access, in this case, the top anchor from an array of anchors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your aim is, but you need to identify the `NSLayoutConstraint` somehow.

I set the identifier of the top constraint as your `LayoutAnchor` type, then `constraints[.top]` was easy to construct. But this is not safe as the array might contain multiple constraints with the same type, or not at all. 
Please note that `constraints[.bottom]` is `nil` as the identifier is not set for the bottom.

Below is a excerpt from the playground to play with, hope it helps.

```
enum LayoutAnchor: String {
    case top
    case left
    case bottom
    case right
}

extension Array where Element: NSLayoutConstraint {
    subscript(anchor: LayoutAnchor) -> NSLayoutConstraint? {
        switch anchor {
        case .top:
            return self.filter { $0.identifier == LayoutAnchor.top.rawValue }.first
        case .bottom:
            return self.filter { $0.identifier == LayoutAnchor.bottom.rawValue }.first
        case .left:
            return self.filter { $0.identifier == LayoutAnchor.left.rawValue }.first
        case .right:
            return self.filter { $0.identifier == LayoutAnchor.right.rawValue }.first
        }
    }
}

let view1 = UIView()
let view2 = UIView()

let top = view1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view2.topAnchor)
top.identifier = LayoutAnchor.top.rawValue

let constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
    top,
    view1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view2.bottomAnchor)
]

constraints[.top]
constraints[.bottom]
```

Comment: All the constraints of a one single view will be contained inside an array.  Therefore, only one type of each constraint will be inside an array of constraints at any one time (I don't ever need to append more than 1 top anchors to the array).  As a result, when I try to access a constraint, it will either return nil or a type of constraint.  What you've created is exactly what I'm after :)